# Remove elemnt of custom class from an array

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of objects of custom class `Component` which doesn't subclass anything, and I want to remove an element from it:

```
var components: [Component] = [comp1, comp2, comp3]

components = components.filter({$0 != comp2}) // Error
```

the error:

```
Binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to two 'Component' operands
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `!==` instead which returns `true` if two objects do not refer to the same instance.

Comment: Thanks, this is the first time I see this kind of operator in swift.